# Same date in select as date-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My goal is to be able to display the same date in two selects as in the date-picker from jquery-ui.

I have created a http://jsfiddle.net/grappler/bzPYg/3/ based off this http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerIntoSelects.html

So this is my code. In the original code if I select a new date in the date-picker the date also changes in the select buttons. Now in the new set up the date doesn't change and I don't know how to have the Month and Year in one field.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/kq5jT/8/)

Thank you for any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Added a CSS from cdn to your fiddle so others can test w/o your server's user/pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery datepicker doesn't have your old plugins' custom events which you were binding, hence you should use the jQuery datepicker's [`onSelect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#events) event to update your `select`s according to the selected date.

```
$('#departdate').datepicker({
    //...
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        updateSelects(dateText);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/kq5jT/15/)

I did some other modifications to your function as well, most notably replacing your `.attr` calls on options by a proper `.val` in the select elements. Both work, but you should avoid using attributes for setting dynamic properties.

You may as well use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead `.bind`, which is the standard preferred way of binding event handlers since jQuery 1.7.

I also slightly modified how you were creating the [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

For the month+year select, I kept the values as they are and applied some basic arithmetic for selecting, you could as well concatenate the month with year in the values (e.g. `1-2012` for Jan-2012 and replace the maths with string concatenation).

Comment: Thaks, it works great. If the the select option were being creaed dynamically with php woulde it still work.

Comment: Yes of course. Post the php code if you have problems implementing it. `=]`

Comment: @grappler I think you forgot to put the `$i`s inside of the `option`s' values, like this: `echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';` (add the value="$i" to the other select as well). Just check if it generates the html like the one in the fiddle and you'll be alright.

Comment: @ Fabricio Ok, thanks that worked. I just realized that it with the current set up I am unable to change the date in the datepicker using the select options. Is it possible to have the date go both ways?